# Folder name change python

Tags: python

Need help to replace a folder name with 'folder name' in python.

Add single quotes before and after the name. I have a list of folder names where I need to implement this.

Input:

```
Name=[folder name,folders,...,fol name]
```

Expected output:

```
Name=['folder name' ,folders,...,'fol name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the list and typecast into str.

```py
Name = [folder_name_1, folder_name_2, ... ]

for idx, folder_name in enumerate(Name):
    Name[idx] = str(folder_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add `'` to the names of your folder list you might want to use `format` function as the following snippet:

```py
inputFolderNames=["folder name","folders", "fol name"]
output = []
for folderName in inputFolderNames:
    output.append("'{}'".format(folderName))
print (output)
```

Where the output is a list with the names of the folders with single quotes.